# Simplifying expresion with Defer and derivatives

Tags: replacement, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation

I would like to simplify a complicated expression that contains some derivatives whose evaluation is halted with `Defer`, using some custom simplification rules. For example, the input

```
Simplify[Defer[D[a, t]] + Defer[D[b, t]], c == a + b]
```

would ideally output $\partial_t c$. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: it will simpler if you write  `D[a[t],t]` instead of `D[a,t]` and same for the other one.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I try Simplify[D[a[t], t] + D[b[t], t], c[t] == a[t] + b[t]] I get a'[t] + b'[t] instead of c'[t]. Is there a way to achieve this simplification? (I don't want to add the derivative rule `c'[t] == a'[t] + b'[t]` explicitly if possible, as it would be very annoying given my true problem at hand)

Comment: when you do `Simplify[D[a[t], t] + D[b[t], t], {c[t] == a[t] + b[t]}]` (I added `{}`), the derivative has already taken place before reaching the end of the command. so there is no more `a[t]` in the expression to replace. There is only `a'[t]` that is why there is nothing to replace.